# Facebook Page access token without creating application

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, facebook-access-token

I am bit confused with the facebook part of getting post from the facebook page for say example
http://www.facebook.com/pages/Favourite-Tv-Shows/448925518469095
For this url i am trying to generate access token from Graph Api Explorer but it gives me token that expires within an hour, As i don't have use of application so is there any way without generating access token for above page without adding application.

Kindly Please help to get me out of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get any `access_token` without using application. `access_token` is bound to application and cannot exists without one...

Actually `access_token` you got using [Graph Api Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), belongs to Application #145634995501895 (aka [Graph Api Explorer](https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=145634995501895))

Comment: Oh So in this case to get the pages post i have to generate application ? Without doing this i cant get it working ? By using graph api i am able to get the access token for the perticular page but that is only for an hour and i am not able to extend the life of it, SO by creating application only i will be able to get permanant access token ?

Comment: @savan, there is no such thing as permanent `access_token` (`offline_access` permission is deprecated and for pages that never existed), you can only extend page's owner `access_token` and use it to get fresh page's `access_token`.

Comment: Ok  Juicy Scripter, Thank you very much for your great help.... Will create a Application and try with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with creating application and then created token for it and used that token directly for my facebook page and it worked like a charm 
thanks a lot for your help